# Is it Possible to Concatenate variable in Split Regexp in Javascript? Eg: var.split(/[A-Z]/+ variable + / \d/);

Tags: javascript, regex

Regexp Javascript , is it possible to concatenate ?

Ex 1: (Working Example)

```
var reg = new RegExp(/(\d+): ([A-Za-z0-9çÇáéíóúãõÁÉÍÓÚÃÕ]+): ([A-Za-z0-9çÇáéíóúãõÁÉÍÓÚÃÕ]+)/);
var arr = all_titles.split(reg);
```

I'm trying to do it but I can't figure it out how to concatenate, cause I actually want to concatenate a variable in it, but if I add the Quotes it just doesn't work.

Ex 2:

```
var reg = new RegExp("/(\d+): ([A-Za-z0-9çÇáéíóúãõÁÉÍÓÚÃÕ]+): ([A-Za-z0-9çÇáéíóúãõÁÉÍÓÚÃÕ]+)/");
var arr = all_titles.split(reg);
```

The Example 2 doesn't work for some reason (without even any concatenation of variable), then I stripped the delimiters and still didn't work.

What I want to do is get something like this ->   20: lalalalala: whateverIsWritten

```
var variable = "lalalalala";
var reg = new RegExp("/(\d+): "+variable+": ([A-Za-z0-9çÇáéíóúãõÁÉÍÓÚÃÕ]+)/");
var arr = all_titles.split(reg);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see that you are trying to support UTF8. You can make it better if you replace çÇáéíóúãõÁÉÍÓÚÃÕ with \u00c0-\u01ff, thus support the more characters with less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile a regular expression from a variable, e.g.:

```
var regex = new RegExp();

var src = "\\s"; // don't forget to escape slashes!
var mods  = "g";
regex.compile(src, mods); 

alert(regex.source);
```

Comment: The RegExp().compile() method is deprecatedt

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
new RegExp("(\\d+): "+variable+": ([A-Za-z0-9çÇáéíóúãõÁÉÍÓÚÃÕ]+)");
```

`\` escaped, `/` removed from start and end.